# Which takes less memory in MongoDB, a number or a string?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make my database as efficient as possible. It's a really simple database in which the collections only have documents that store either strings, or numbers or booleans. No arrays, mixed data types etc. If I want to store 24 as the value of one of the fields (which will only contain natural numbers). Which would take less space

```
{
 field: 24
}
```

or

```
{
 field: "24"
}
```

I'm using mongoose, and what I'm basically asking is that should I set `Number` or `String` as the type in my `Schema` for that particular field.

Comment: Please note that you can't issue some queries if you're using *Stringly Numbers*. For example, if you save `{age : "25"}`, you can't perform range queries on `age` like `{$gt: {age: "25"}}`. The only reason to select a data type shouldn't be the *Efficiency*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store numbers as `Number`s.

MongoDB uses [BSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) ([spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html)). `Number` in this context usually means a 64-bit IEEE-754 floating-point number (what BSON calls a `double`), so that's going to take...64 bits. :-) Add to that the overhead (according to the spec) of saying it's a number (one byte) and the field name (the length of the name plus one byte), but as those will be the same for `Number` and `String` we can disregard them. So 64 bits for `Number`.

The spec says `String` is stored as a 32-bit length followed by the string in UTF-8 followed by a terminator byte (plus the overhead in common with `Number`). That's `32 + (8 x number_of_bytes_in_utf_8) + 8` bits for a string.

Each of the characters used to represent numbers in strings (`-`, `+`, `0`-`9`, `e`/`E` [for scientific notation], and `.`) are represented with a single byte in UTF-8, so for our purposes in this question, # of chars = # of bytes.

So:

- For `"24"` it's `32 + (8 x 2) + 8` giving us 56 bits.
- For `"254"` it's `32 + (8 x 3) + 8` giving us 64 bits.
- For `"2254"` it's `32 + (8 x 4) + 8` giving us 72 bits.
- For `"1.334"` it's `32 + (8 x 5) + 8` giving us 80 bits.

See where I'm going with this? :-)

Add to that the fact that if it's a number, then storing it as a string:

- ...imposes a runtime penalty (converting to and fron string)
- ...means you can't do range comparisons like [Ali Dehghani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393484/ali-dehghani)'s [`{$gt: {age: "25"}}` example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743651/which-takes-less-memory-in-mongodb-a-number-or-a-string/37743844#comment62957838_37743651)

...and I'd say `Number` is your clear choice.